# How to send an app invitation with Spring Social 1.1.0

Tags: java, facebook, spring, spring-social

I am working on a facebook game and I want a player to send an invitation to his/her friend. I tried facebook.feedOperations.postLink(...) but I get org.springframework.social.InsufficientPermissionException: Insufficient permission for this operation.

Which function should I use and which permissions does my facebook app need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok 
I added **publish_stream** extended permission to my app and now it works.

Comment: for those who dont know where to give publish_stream; first you need a facebook app created on facebook, if you have it created you can give this permission from developers.facebook.com app settings.

Comment: I've not yet confirmed this, but I believe that Facebook recently removed the ability to post to someone else's timeline. Therefore, this may not work for you as of the past couple of days. Also know that what you were posting is just a link. There's also such thing as an invitation, but it has never been possible to send an invitation via the Graph API (and thus not possible with Spring Social). The appropriate way to send an invitation is with the app requests Javascript dialog. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368002/send-facebook-app-request-invite-using-graph-api